# Select from e insert into em outro database com Python

Tags: python, postgresql, microsoft-azure

Estou tentando fazer um select em um DB da azure e após isso inserir os dados em um DB postgreSQL.

Testei as conexões separadas e ambas estão funcionando, porém ao executar o código completo não acontece nada até acusar time out do DB.

Versões:
Python 3, 
PostgreSQL 10.6,
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Podem me dar uma luz? Segue meu código:

```
import pyodbc
import psycopg2

#conn azure
server_azure = 'server'
database_azure = 'database'
username_azure = 'username'
password_azure = 'password'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn_azure = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

#conn postgresql
cnxn_postgre = psycopg2.connect("dbname='dbname' user='user' host='host' 
password='password'")
cursor_postgre = cnxn_postgre.cursor()

cursor_azure = cnxn_azure.cursor()
cursor_azure.execute(
"select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6  from tabela"
row = cursor.fetchone()
for row in rows
    cursor_postgre.execute(""" INSERT INTO "tabela2" (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') """)

cursor_azure.commit()
cursor_azure.close()
cursor_postgre.close()
```

Comment: Seria bem esclarecedor se você passasse as versões do python, SQL...

Comment: Matheus, obrigado pelo comentário. Acabei de inserir as versões que estou utilizando. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Maursb, pelo que vi no seu código, tem um erro no FOR

altere a linha 20 para que fique assim

```
rows = cursor.fetchone()
```